# How to read certain part of document of type NSTextView?

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa

I have NSScrollview window, when I click on some part of that document I want to get that perticular word from it.

Comment: What kind of document is it?

Comment: [NSView SetDocumentView: NSTextView];